# Use names of named ranges in formula in Epplus

Tags: epplus

I'm using Epplus in a .NET Core application and I'd like to use names of named ranges in formulas. The issue is that when I reference a named range it takes the value of the first cell in range and don't iterate through rows:

```
    var data = new List<object[]>()
{
    new object[] {"Hours", "Price", "Total"},
    new object[] {0.5, 10, 0},
    new object[] {2, 100, 0},
    new object[] {3, 20, 0}
};

using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
{
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Variables");
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromArrays(data);

    sheet.Names.Add("Hours", sheet.Cells["A2:A4"]);
    sheet.Names.Add("Price", sheet.Cells["B2:B4"]);
    sheet.Names.Add("Total", sheet.Cells["C2:C4"]);

    sheet.Names["Total"].Formula = "Hours * Price";

    package.Workbook.Calculate();

    for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{sheet.Cells[i, 1].Value}\t{sheet.Cells[i, 2].Value}\t{sheet.Cells[i, 3].Value}");
    }
}
```

This code writes the following to the console:

```
Hours   Price   Total
0,5     10      5
2       100     5
3       20      5
```

But actually I'd like to get this:

```
Hours   Price   Total
0,5     10      5
2       100     200
3       20      60
```

Is it possible to somehow do that using names as arguments instead of cell addresses, like "Hours * Price"?

Answer (score 0):

EPPlus `Calculate()` doesn't seem to support named ranges in formulas. But if your console output is only for test, the formulas are calculated correctly if you save the file and open it. I.e. if you add `using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(someFileName)))` and `package.Save();` inside the using statement.

The console output would be correct if your formula uses the cell addresses (but guessing that's not good enough for you):

```
for (int col = 2; col < 5; col++)
    sheet.Cells[$"C{col}"].Formula = $"A{col} * B{col}";
```